# Unable to trigger onmouseenter events?

Tags: javascript

I was able to make onmousesenter work correctly when I included the reference to the function directly in the html, but read that was bad form and wanted to improve my code- but now I can't get it to run, despite my code showing it does trigger the function, I'm just not sure why the rest of it fails to run now:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<title>Sexism in Silicon Valley</title>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body1">
<div class="parent">
    <img src="kstartup.png" class="logos" id="id1"></img>
    <img src="uber.png" class="logos" id="id2"></img>
    <img src="kpcb.png" class="logos" id="id3"></img>
    <img id="id4" src="r1startup.png" class="logos"></img>
</div>
```

Javascript (index.js):

```
function mouseenter() { 
    alert("hey");
    var z = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        z[i].style.background = "black";
    } 
    var bod = document.getElementById("body1");
    bod.style.background = "black";

} 
document.getElementById("id1").onmouseenter = mouseenter();
```

The alert goes off as soon as I load the page instead of when my mouse enters the id1. Why isn't it triggered by my mouse entering the id?

Comment: should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I changed this and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document DOM is not ready when you try to access the ID `id1` Element.

```
document.getElementById("id1").onmouseenter = mouseenter; // Don't execute()
// Since this code is inside HEAD, JS does not know about any #id1 Element yet.
```

cause you're calling the `<script>` tag inside `<head>` instead of at the bottom before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="index.js"></script> <!-- Makes sure parser readed all the elements -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AllisonStafford you're welcome. Beside !DOCTYPE etc typos,  make also sure to remove the `</img>` tags! IMG is a **Void** element (like `<input>`) and does not accepts a closing tag!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("id1").onmouseenter = mouseenter; // << no ()
// Assign, don't execute.
```

Comment: You are thinking of jQuery selectors.

Comment: ya sorry, confused it with jquery.. my bad

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, why on earth did you update this incorrect answer to complete change its content?

Comment: @JamesHenry I have special powers

Comment: I didn't ask, "how could you?", I asked "why did you?". I hope you are very proud that you came in and answered a question which was edited beyond recognition, and also invalidated a flag on an entirely inaccurate answer. This is meant to be helpful community.

Comment: @James Henry this question wasn't rockets science, I would have edited it myself but Roko did it first.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of issues here:

- The doctype is incorrect
- Image tags do not have a closing equivalent in HTML5, i.e. `</img>` does not exist (was a thing in XHTML)
- You have not wrapped you JavaScript in `<script>` tags so it is being interpreted as HTML
- You are calling the mouseenter function when you are assigning it, so you actually assigning the result. In other words you should just assign a reference to the function: `document.getElementById("id1").onmouseenter = mouseenter`

Working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fmBIM7U6QSS0cl7vqdlQ?p=preview (obviously the images will not load, as you only provided relative paths)

Comment: I should have looked harder, there are a number of points to address here, I will update my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, the jscript is in another file that i'm calling in between script tags.

Comment: I changed everything you said and it still does not work. I deleted the closing img tags, fixed the <!DOCTYPE html>, I'm calling the javascript so it's not being evaluated as html, and I changed the mouseenter thing.

Comment: I don't understand, I provided you with a working example in the answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/fmBIM7U6QSS0cl7vqdlQ?p=preview

Comment: Yes, you did everything correctly, but I didn't realize your decision to put the script tags at the bottom of your html wasn't arbitrary.

Comment: All's well that ends well :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it! <3